# How to count rows in a column, per period, and per category, then rank them, in Power BI using DAX?

Tags: powerbi, dax

Below is an example of what I am trying to do.
I have the first two columns in the Table and want to add column three and four.

Is there a DAX way to do this?
I've tried GROUPBY, SUMMARIZE and RANX but can't seem to work it out.

| period | animal | count_animal_per_period | rank_animal_per_period |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Period 1 | cat | 4 | 1 |
| Period 1 | cat | 4 | 1 |
| Period 1 | dog | 2 | 2 |
| Period 1 | cat | 4 | 1 |
| Period 1 | dog | 2 | 2 |
| Period 1 | bird | 1 | 3 |
| Period 1 | cat | 4 | 1 |
| Period 2 | dog | 4 | 1 |
| Period 2 | dog | 4 | 1 |
| Period 2 | dog | 4 | 1 |
| Period 2 | cat | 2 | 2 |
| Period 2 | cat | 2 | 2 |
| Period 2 | bird | 1 | 3 |
| Period 2 | dog | 4 | 1 |
| Period 3 | cat | 4 | 1 |
| Period 3 | bird | 2 | 2 |
| Period 3 | cat | 4 | 1 |
| Period 3 | cat | 4 | 1 |
| Period 3 | dog | 1 | 3 |
| Period 3 | bird | 2 | 2 |
| Period 3 | cat | 4 | 1 |

Answer (score 0):

Two calculation:

```
Count_animal_per_periods = 

var __count = CALCULATE( COUNTROWS('Sheet2 (2)'), FILTER(ALL('Sheet2 (2)'[animal],'Sheet2 (2)'[period]), 'Sheet2 (2)'[animal] = SELECTEDVALUE('Sheet2 (2)'[animal]) && 'Sheet2 (2)'[period] = SELECTEDVALUE('Sheet2 (2)'[period])))

return

__count
```

And second:

```
rank_animal = RANKX (
        FILTER(
            ALL(
                'Sheet2 (2)'[period],
                'Sheet2 (2)'[animal]
                ),
            'Sheet2 (2)'[period] = MAX('Sheet2 (2)'[period])
            ),
            [Count_animal_per_periods]
            )
```

[image]

Comment: I was trying to do this by adding columns. That way I can further filter the data set with other items in the row. Such as filtering if rank equal under 5, or the month and year for the period.

Comment: In powerbi You can filter visualization by measure. In a measure, we can also refer to another measure, but we must put it to variable for example 
VAR __Rank = [rank_animal]  return __Rank = 3